# Stock Splits -- What are surplus and capital accounts?

Tags: stocks, stock-split

I just read this in The Intelligent Investor, by Benjamin Graham:

> A stock split may be carried out by what technically may be called a stock dividend, which **involves a transfer of sums from earned surplus to capital account**; or else by a change in par value, which does not affect the surplus account.

I know about the second method of stock splitting: just divide the shares and price!
But the first one I never heard of, and haven't been able to find it online.
It seems that transferring money "from surplus to capital account" would just make the shares pricier?

**Could you please explain this method of stock splitting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just how the dividend is accounted for on the company's financial statements. As a company earns profits, it increases an account on the Balance Sheet called "Retained Earnings" (sometimes called "Earned Surplus"). When a company pays a cash dividend, that amount is removed from both cash and retained earnings (since the earnings are no longer "retained" by the company, but distributed to the owners).

A stock dividend is when a company issues additional shares of stock *instead* of cash. It *also* reduces retained earnings, but instead of reducing cash, it is added to two equity accounts - "capital stock" and "additional paid-in capital". The additional paid-in capital is the amount of the stock dividend that exceeded the "par" amount of the stock. It's the same calculation when a company issues shares directly.  Since they are both equity accounts, the value of the company does not change (unlike a cash dividend which reduces the value of the company) - it's just divided into more shares.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just wanted to add that: Graham is saying that a stock dividend is a stock split [see quote above] because it does dilute the value of each share. (Would you agree?)

Comment: Mathematically it's the same effect, yes. You have more shares but the company is worth the same amount, to the value per share is less.